# Linq Distinct not bringing back the correct results

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to select a distinct values from a `DataTable` using `Linq`. The `DataTable` gets populated from an excel sheet which has dynamic column apart from each excel sheet has a column name `SERIAL NUMBER` which is mandatory.

I have a `DataTable` for demo purpose which consist of 4 serial number as:

- 12345
- 12345
- 98765
- 98765

When I do

```
var distinctList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a).Distinct().ToList();
```

If I do

```
var distinctList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER").Distinct().ToList();
```

Then I get the correct results, however but it only contains the one column from `dt` and not all the other columns

I get all four records instead of 2. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Comment: You want distinct by all column in the datatable?

Comment: @Magnus I want to distinct by `serial number` column only, and if there's more only return one of them and the other place it in a duplicate list so I can eventually warn the users of all the duplicates found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to group them by Serial Number and retrieve the full DataRow? Assuming that after grouping them we want to retrieve the first item:

```
var distinctList = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(a => a.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER"))
                       .Select(a => a.FirstOrDefault()).Distinct().ToList();
```

EDIT: As requested

```
var distinctValues = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER")).Distinct().ToList();
var duplicateValues = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(a => a.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER")).SelectMany(a => a.Skip(1)).Distinct().ToList();
var duplicatesRemoved = dt.AsEnumerable().Except(duplicateValues);
```

Comment: Sorry I think I might have been unclear in my question. I want to get the distinct values only and remove the duplicates/add them to another list if possible. I don't want to group them

Comment: Thanks for this, what is the reason for you to use `Skip(1)` here?

Comment: So, by grouping them by SerialNumber, we will get several collections of items each of which share the same SN. With **.SelectMany()** we retrieve all the items of each collection into a flat list, but we want to **skip** or **avoid** the **first item** so that we don't include the "original" or "first" entry for that SN, we only want the duplicates after all. Is it clear?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Distinct` method by default uses the default equality comparer, which for `DataRow` is comparing by **reference**. To get the desired result, you can use the `Distinct` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to pass `IEqualityComparer<T>`, and pass [`DataRowComparer.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The DataRowComparer<TRow> class is used to compare the values of the DataRow objects and does not compare the object references.

```
var distinctList = dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default).ToList();
```

For more info, see [Comparing DataRows (LINQ to DataSet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386998(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try it and let you know how I get on

Answer (score 2):

In ToTable method the first parameter specifies if you want `Distinct` records, the second specify by which column name we will make distinct.

```
DataTable returnVals = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ColumnNameOnWhichYouWantDistinctRecords");
```

Here there is no need to use linq for this task !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this only returns me the `SERIAL NUMBER` column

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq a GroupBy would be better suited, by the sounds of it.

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(a => a.SerialNumber).Select(_ => new {Key = _.Key, Items = _});
```

This will then contain groupings based on the Serial Number. With each group of items having the same serial number, but other property values different.

Comment: But this won't give me a distinct list instead it will group the two items under one serial which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<string> distinctValues = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select row.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER")).Distinct().ToList();
```

However to me this also works:

```
List<string> distinctValues = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER")).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: But that will only return me a list with `SERIAL NUMBER` column I want all the other columns too. Your query is exactly the same as what I've already put in my question